# PHP is replacing ® with?

Tags: php, unit-testing, automated-tests

I'm trying to write a PHP script that verifies if the correct programs and libraries are correctly installed in the user's machine.

I generate a list of programs with the following line of code:

```
$installed_programs_list = shell_exec("wmic product get name,version /format:csv");
```

There is one line that should be

Intel® Trusted Connect Service Client,1.28.487.1

but my string comparison is failing because the $installed_programs_list variable has Intelr Trusted Connect Service Client,1.28.487.1.

I tried to play with the mb_detect_encondig and it does not seem to be able to detect that line. It shows ASCII for all other lines but nothing for Intel® line. I tried to force to UTF-8 but no luck. I don't know if I did it right.

I tried saving the output to a .csv file and reading back with fread() and the string shows Intel�

here is my code:

```
shell_exec("wmic product get name,version /format:csv > software_list.csv");
// get contents of a file into a string
$filename1 = "software_list.csv";
$handle = fopen($filename1, "rb");
$installed_programs_list = fread($handle, filesize($filename1));
fclose($handle);

echo $installed_programs_list;
```

Further below:

```
    //check if correct programs are installed
    foreach($installed_programs as $value){
        if(mb_strpos($installed_programs_list, trim($value)) === false){
            print_div("$value not installed.", "red");
            $test_passed = 0;   
        }else{
            print_div("$value installed.", "blue");
        }
    }
```

My goal is to create a series of automated tests for my company in PHP.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: did u try header content type utf8

Comment: Did you use `utf8_encode()` to force the change, rather than `mb_convert_encoding()`. I've had issues with converting some `ISO-8859-1` chars with `mb_convert_encoding()` but those problems don't seem to arise when using `utf8_encode()`

Comment: @craig_h yes u r right it will resolve if u use utf8 header

Comment: using the hex editor I was able to see that there is a '0xC2' before ®. Notepad++ does not show the character. I only see Intel® but it is there. So the challenge is to make PHP execute a binary comparison. header() does not help since the problem is with the input not the output.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings that stem from two sources:

1. `$installed_programs_list` is generated by `wmic`
2. `$installed_programs` is probably declared in your PHP file

Comparing the values can fail if the values in those variables have different encodings, and special characters are represented differently: `0xC2 0xA9` in UTF-8, `0x00A9` in UTF-16, `0xA9` in ISO-8859-15.

You have to find out (e.g. with a hex editor) which encoding the CSV file has, and your IDE/Text editor should show you which encoding your PHP file has. Align them, or convert one to the other with `mb_convert_encoding`.